# jQuery - Check if multiple radio button groups are selected, then return name of those who aren't

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, input, radio-button

I have +90 questions in a survey. Each question has 5 choices. The questions is built by 
database information.

I need to check if all the questions were answered, and if one of them wasn't, then this should be alerted.

They are all divided into radio button groups, and I would like to use jQuery to check.

The if statement won't work, the only think that gets alerted is: " is NOT checked!"

```
<div class='aQuestion' id='div1'>
    <STRONG>1. </STRONG>
    <STRONG>Question</STRONG></br>
    <INPUT TYPE='radio' NAME='grp1' VALUE='0'>answer 1</br>
    <INPUT TYPE='radio' NAME='grp1' VALUE='1'>answer 2</br>
    <INPUT TYPE='radio' NAME='grp1' VALUE='2'>answer 3</br>
    <INPUT TYPE='radio' NAME='grp1' VALUE='3'>answer 4</br>
    <INPUT TYPE='radio' NAME='grp1' VALUE='4'>answer 5
</div>

<div class='aQuestion' id='div2'>
    <STRONG>2. </STRONG>
    <STRONG>Question</STRONG></br>
    <INPUT TYPE='radio' NAME='grp2' VALUE='0'>answer 1</br>
    <INPUT TYPE='radio' NAME='grp2' VALUE='1'>answer 2</br>
    <INPUT TYPE='radio' NAME='grp2' VALUE='2'>answer 3</br>
    <INPUT TYPE='radio' NAME='grp2' VALUE='3'>answer 4</br>
    <INPUT TYPE='radio' NAME='grp2' VALUE='4'>answer 5
</div>
```

( And there are 8 more those questions as above )

```
<script>

    jQuery('#submit').click(function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();

        for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
        {               
            var currentGroup = "grp" + i;

            if($("input[name=currentGroup]:checked").val())
            {
                alert(currentGroup + ' is checked!');                
            }
            else 
            {
                alert(currentGroup + ' is NOT checked!');
            }    
        }
    });

</script>
```

Thanks in advance. And if anyone has an idea how to make users browser view jump to the questions that weren't answered, then I would like to hear that too ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to traverse each div with class `aQuestion` by using `.each()` and you need to check whether any radio buttons are checked inside that of element by using `.find()`.

Try,

```
$('.aQuestion').each(function(){
  if($(this).find('input[type="radio"]:checked').length > 0)
    {
       alert("checked");
    }
  else
    {
       alert("not checked");
    }    
});
```

As mplungjan suggested you can also use,

```
$('.aQuestion').each(function(){ 
  $(this).toggleClass("didntmakechoice",$(this).find('input[type="radio"]:checked').length == 0);
});
```

Comment: Do you know how to use jQuery on the div's that isn't checked ?

Comment: @user3033005 Yes.. obviously the else part is actually points the div which do not have a checked radio button. Right.?

Comment: Thx. How would you target the specific div?

Comment: $( someLinkToTheDiv ).addClass( "didntMakeChoice" );  <--- Something like that. I dont know how to link to the actual div ;)

Comment: @user3033005 In the else part just write, `$(this).addClass('didntmakechoice');` Simple isn't.? :)

Comment: Sorry. Got too excited asking questions hehe. Thanks a lot !

Comment: How about `$('.aQuestion').each(function(){
 $(this).toggleClass("OK",$(this).find('input[type="radio"]:checked').length > 0)}`

Comment: @mplungjan Great way to simplify that if else statement. Nice.

Comment: @rajaprabhu and mplungjan, thanks for the answers. They work like a charm. If you have the time for it, could you then make a small example of jQuery code, that makes animation to the div that hasn't been answered. I'we tried to use .animate(), but I cant figure it out. Thanks a lot in advance.